liquibase upgradation from 3.6.3 to 4.9.1 resulting in executing the file which are already executed
We are upgrading spring boot(2.1.6.Release to 2.7.18) which in turn upgrading liquibase from 3.6.3 to 4.9.1 resulting in executing the file which are already executed.
Looks like the new version of liquibase is generating new MD5Sum which is different than the already existing MD5Sum for the same xml file which is resulting in rerunning the file which are executed. which is causing the issue ..Please help us to resolve the issue.

You are correct. The checksum calculation algorithm has changed.
You can fix your issue using Liquibase CLI. Execute the following commands:

Run liquibase clear-checksums. This will clear the checksums of the previous changesets. Docs are here

Run liquibase update. This will run all not prevously ran changeSets. Liquibase decides whether chageset has been ran or not based on ID, author and path to filename.  Docs are here.


After that all your changesets should have new checksums, and you should be able to continue writing new changesets as usual using new Liquibase version.
